# Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении вкладки через кнопку не удалялась предыдущая вкладка? (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, вкладки

В приложении есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую добавляется вкладка. При повторном нажатии на кнопку эта вкладка заменяется на новую. Как сделать так, чтобы первая вкладка оставалась и добавлялась новая?
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
# создание вкладки
def note1(window, nam1):
    notebook.add(note, text=nam1.get())
    note.place()
    window.grab_release()
    window.destroy()
 
# создание второго окна
def root2():
    window = Toplevel(bg="#16141A")
    window.title("Новая заметка")
    window.geometry("250x100")
    name1 = Label(window, text="Название заметки:", bg="#16141A", fg="White", font=("Arial", 15))
    name1.place(x=0)
    nam1 = Entry(window, bg="#111014", fg="White", font=("Arial", 12))
    nam1.place(x=5, y=35, width=160)
    # кнопка для создания вкладки
    btn = Button(window, text="Создать", bg="#2E2833", fg="White", relief=FLAT, font=("Arial", 12), command=lambda: note1(window, nam1))
    btn.place(x=35, y=60, width=100, height=20)
    nam1.insert(0, "Новая заметка")
    window.grab_set()

# создание основного окна
root1 = Tk()
root1.title('Заметки')
root1.geometry('1000x700')
root1.option_add("*tearOff", FALSE)

# создание основной вкладки
notebook = ttk.Notebook()
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
note = ttk.Frame(notebook, height=950)
memo = ttk.Frame(notebook, height=950)

notebook.add(frame1, text="Главное меню")

# виджеты на основной вкладке
can = Canvas(frame1, width=1000, height=700)
can.pack(anchor=SW)
can.create_rectangle(0, 0, 300, 700, fill="#16141A")
can.create_rectangle(300, 0, 1000, 700, fill="#111014")

lbl = Label(frame1, text="Добро пожаловать!", bg="#111014", fg="White", font=("Arial", 35))
can.create_window((650, 100), anchor=CENTER, window=lbl)

btn1 = Button(frame1, bg="#2172FF", relief=FLAT, text="Создать заметку", font=("Arial", 18), activebackground="#2172FF", command=lambda: root2())
btn1.place(x=25, y=20, width=250, height=50)
btn1 = Button(frame1, bg="#2172FF", relief=FLAT, text="Создать памятку", font=("Arial", 18), activebackground="#2172FF", command=lambda: note2())
btn1.place(x=25, y=75, width=250, height=50)

root1.mainloop()
```

Переписал функцию и все получилось

```
    def note1(window, nam1):
        notebook1 = ttk.Notebook()
        notebook1.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        note = ttk.Frame(notebook, height=950)
        notebook.add(note, text=nam1.get())
        note.place()
        window.grab_release()
        window.destroy()
```

Comment: Создание самой заметки (note) перенесите в функцию ее добавления в notebook. Должна каждый раз новая заметка создаваться, а вы сейчас только одну создали при старте программы и только имя ей меняете. Нужно создавать новый объект, тогда он будет добавляться отдельной вкладкой.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло